# is it possible to modify porter stemmer result?

Tags: porter-stemmer

I've used porter stemmer in my project(using python). but I see some errors in output. for example the term "intrductory" changed to "introductori" instead of "introduct".
is it possible to improve this result?

Answer (score 0):

Why do you think it is an error? Step 2 in the `Porter Stemmer` algorithm states:

> Step2() turns terminal 'y' to 'i' when there is another vowel in the stem.

So `introductory` should indeed be converted to `introductori`

That said, if you do want to break it down to a base word you can do so in `Step4()`

```
case 'i': if (ends("iciti")) { r("ic"); break; }
          if (ends("tori")) { r("t"); break; }
          break;
```